# cancel ALL kivy clocks from seperate file

Tags: kivy, clock

in my kivy app , i have around 15 modules and *.kv files. In a couple of those files i have started a clock with for example this clock event that triggers every 5 minutes

```
self.updating_my_coordinates = Clock.schedule_once(self.trigger_database_update, 300)
```

When i "log out" of the app from a logout button in a seperate module to the clock code, it takes me to the sign in screen, but i notice in the console the active clock events are still triggering. So my question is... How do i cancel ALL active clocks in a kivy app from a method in a seperate module to where the clocks originate from ?

Obviously calling self.updating_my_coordinates.cancel() from the logout modules method fails cause there is no self.updating_my_coordinates

also tried

```
Clock.unschedule(all=True)
```

but that requires 1 positional arg

My brains failing to understand the document at https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html for this situation and would like some advise please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question

Now that i'm a little more familiar with the operations of kivy.....In the end, the way i cancelled a clock from a different screen was simply do a

`App.get_running_app().root.get_screen("screen_name").cancelClock()`

then added

```
def cancelClock(self):
    Clock.unschedule(updating_my_coordinates)
```

Where "screenName" is the screen that the event was started from
and
updating_my_coordinates is the name of the event

right or wrong, it worked :) hope that helps another newbie one day

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33534934)